# Ambiguous template function specialization compile error

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm currently trying to make a set of conversion functions which, through one call, can (attempt to) convert a JavaScript object (`CefV8Value`) into its C++ counterpart, with support for pointers.

Here are the conversion functions (pointer conversion at the end):

```
template<typename T>
T convert_v8value_to_cpp(const CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> &value) {};

// Explicit type conversion functions
#define V8VALUE_TO_CPP_CONVERSION(type) \
      template<> type \
      convert_v8value_to_cpp<type>(const CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> &value)

V8VALUE_TO_CPP_CONVERSION(CefRefPtr<CefV8Value>)
{
    return value;
}

V8VALUE_TO_CPP_CONVERSION(bool)
{
    return value->GetBoolValue();
}

V8VALUE_TO_CPP_CONVERSION(int)
{
    return value->GetIntValue();
}

V8VALUE_TO_CPP_CONVERSION(std::string)
{
    return value->GetStringValue().ToString();
}

V8VALUE_TO_CPP_CONVERSION(const char *)
{
    return value->GetStringValue().ToString().c_str();
}

V8VALUE_TO_CPP_CONVERSION(std::wstring)
{
    return value->GetStringValue().ToWString();
}

// HACKHACK: most VGUI functions take non-const wchar_t pointers, when they
// shouldn't
V8VALUE_TO_CPP_CONVERSION(wchar_t *)
{
    return (wchar_t*)value->GetStringValue().ToWString().c_str();
}

V8VALUE_TO_CPP_CONVERSION(const wchar_t *)
{
    return value->GetStringValue().ToWString().c_str();
}

V8VALUE_TO_CPP_CONVERSION(double)
{
    return value->GetDoubleValue();
}

V8VALUE_TO_CPP_CONVERSION(float)
{
    return value->GetDoubleValue();
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Purpose: converts a JS array to a C++ vector (of type T)
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> convert_v8value_to_cpp(const CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> &value)
{
    std::vector<T> vec;

    if(!value->IsArray())
        return vec;

    for(int i = 0; i < value->GetArrayLength(); ++i)
    {
        CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> element = value->GetValue(i);
        vec.push_back(convert_v8value_to_cpp<T>(element));
    }

    return vec; // hopefully move semantics will optimise this and not copy-construct
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Purpose: converts a JS object to a C++ pointer (where T is a pointer type)
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T>::value, T>::type
    convert_v8value_to_cpp(const CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> &value)
{
    if(!value->IsObject())
        return NULL;

    CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> pTypeId = value->GetValue("__v8bind_typeid__");
    if(!pTypeId || !pTypeId->IsString())
        return NULL;

    CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> pPointerVal = value->GetValue("__v8bind_ptr__");
    if(!pPointerVal || !pPointerVal->IsInt())
        return NULL;

    if(pTypeId->GetStringValue().ToString() == typeid(T).name())
        return (T)pPointerVal->GetIntValue();

    return NULL;
}
```

And here's the code that is using said pointer function:

```
WrapClass *pThis = convert_v8value_to_cpp<WrapClass*>(object);
```

**Visual Studio** complains that:

```
error C2668: 'convert_v8value_to_cpp' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
binding_test.cpp(106): could be 'Point *convert_v8value_to_cpp<WrapClass*>(const CefRefPtr<T> &)'
with
[
   WrapClass=Point,
   T=CefV8Value
]

binding_test.cpp(88): or       'std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> convert_v8value_to_cpp<WrapClass*>(const CefRefPtr<T> &)'
with
[
   _Ty=Point *,
   _Ax=std::allocator<Point *>,
   WrapClass=Point,
   T=CefV8Value
]

binding_test.cpp(31): or       'T convert_v8value_to_cpp<WrapClass*>(const CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> &)'
with
[
   T=Point *,
   WrapClass=Point
]

while trying to match the argument list '(CefRefPtr<T>)'
with
[
   T=CefV8Value
]
```

I don't understand how the call is ambiguous (other than `WrapClass *` matches the first conversion function of `T`). However it also says that a possible call candidate is the `std::vector` conversion. How is this possible?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: See the answer below. Additionally your conversions to char *, wchar_t * and wchar_t const * return pointers to temporary which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I didn't notice, I originally thought the To[W]String() functions returned references... thanks Tomek!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both of these:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> convert_v8value_to_cpp(const CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> &value)
{ ... }

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T>::value, T>::type
convert_v8value_to_cpp(const CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> &value)
{ ... }
```

are not function partial specialisations (which are not allowed anyway), but overloads, so together with the primary function template they're all three ambiguous, because they only differ from each other in the return type.

You want your function template `convert_v8value_to_cpp` to delegate to a static function (`do_it()`, say) in a class template `convert_v8value_to_cpp_helper`, because unlike function templates class templates *can* be specialised.

Primary class template:

```
template <typename T>
struct convert_v8value_to_cpp_helper {}; // no do_it() here by intention
```

Full specialisations:

```
// Explicit type conversion functions
#define V8VALUE_TO_CPP_CONVERSION(type, code) \
template <> struct convert_v8value_to_cpp_helper< type > { \
  static T do_it() code \
}

V8VALUE_TO_CPP_CONVERSION(bool, {return value->GetBoolValue();});
V8VALUE_TO_CPP_CONVERSION(int,  {return value->GetIntValue(); });
V8VALUE_TO_CPP_CONVERSION(std::string,
{ return value->GetStringValue().ToString(); });
V8VALUE_TO_CPP_CONVERSION(const char *,
{ return value->GetStringValue().ToString().c_str(); });
V8VALUE_TO_CPP_CONVERSION(std::wstring,
{ return value->GetStringValue().ToWString(); });
// HACKHACK: most VGUI functions take non-const wchar_t pointers, when they
// shouldn't
V8VALUE_TO_CPP_CONVERSION(wchar_t *,
{ return (wchar_t*)value->GetStringValue().ToWString().c_str(); });
V8VALUE_TO_CPP_CONVERSION(const wchar_t *,
{ return value->GetStringValue().ToWString().c_str(); });
V8VALUE_TO_CPP_CONVERSION(double, {return value->GetDoubleValue();});
V8VALUE_TO_CPP_CONVERSION(float,  {return value->GetDoubleValue();});
```

Specialisation for `std::vector` (incl. those with a custom allocator):

```
template<typename T, typename A>
struct convert_v8value_to_cpp< std::vector<T,A> > {
    static std::vector<T,A> do_it(const CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> &value)
    {
        std::vector<T,A> vec;

        if (!value->IsArray())
            return vec;

        for(int i = 0; i < value->GetArrayLength(); ++i)
        {
            CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> element = value->GetValue(i);
            vec.push_back(convert_v8value_to_cpp<T>(element));
        }

        return vec; // return value optimisation will kick in here
    }
};
```

And, finally, the specialisation for pointers:

```
template<typename T>
struct convert_v8value_to_cpp<T*> { // no need for enable_if
    static T* do_it(const CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> &value)
    {
        if (!value->IsObject())
            return nullptr; // don't use NULL in C++

        CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> pTypeId = value->GetValue("__v8bind_typeid__");
        if (!pTypeId || !pTypeId->IsString())
            return nullptr;

        CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> pPointerVal = value->GetValue("__v8bind_ptr__");
        if (!pPointerVal || !pPointerVal->IsInt())
            return nullptr;

        if (pTypeId->GetStringValue().ToString() == typeid(T).name())
            return (T*)pPointerVal->GetIntValue();

        return nullptr;
    }
};
```

These are now used in the real function template:

```
template <typename T>
T convert_v8value_to_cpp(const CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> &value)
{ return convert_v8value_to_cpp_helper<T>::do_it(value); }
```

There's no more ambiguity because there's only one function template (but there might be ambiguity if partial template specialisation ordering fails to find a single best match, but that shouldn't be the case here).

Answer (score 2):

mmutz explain why it's ambiguous (you have three overloads taking exactly the same argument type that can all match `convert_v8value_to_cpp<WrapClass*>`)

Edit: I see mmutz has also now added a solution, similar to mine below.  I find it much easier to read it written out in full, the macros don't make it easier for me to read and don't even save much typing.

If you want to partially-specialize a template you need to use a class:

```
template<typename T>
struct Converter;

template<>
struct Converter<bool>
{
  typedef bool result_type;
  static result_type convert(const CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> &value)
  { ... }
};

template<typename T>
struct Converter<std::vector<T>>
{
  typedef std::vector<T> result_type;
  static result_type convert(const CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> &value)
  { ... }
};

template<typename T>
struct Converter<T*>
{
  typedef T* result_type;
  static result_type convert(const CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> &value)
  { ... }
};

template<typename T>
typename Converter<T>::result_type
convert_v8value_to_cpp(const CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> &value)
{ return Converter<T>::convert(value); }
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathon. Both answers are exactly what I wanted to know, and I've learnt in the process. However as Marc Mutz answered first I must accept his.

Comment: His answer is more complete anyway! :) glad it helped you understand